# How to transform from selected vertices to circle?

Tags: modeling

I am following a tutorial in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thgu2sVzfMI&t=431s) to model a perfume bottle.

I lost my way on how to do this **transformation from selected vertices to a circle** (refer 0.44 seconds in the video). I have tried many keys and found nothing could help me.

Appreciate your advices..

THANKS!

[image]

Comment: @Dimali. Exactly that. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> -> Connect Vertices with a custom shortcut.

Comment: Or [*Connect Vertex Path*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html) which has a shortcut of `J`.